# Python Text And Row reading error

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I am currently studying computer science as a GCSE student. Me and my teacher are struggling with task 3. The requirements of the task are: 
It then needs to ask the user what class they would like to view
After this it will need to ask if they would like to view the file sorted    alphabetically, the high scores of the particular class or if they would like to view the average of each student in the selected class

```
import csv
class_a = open('classA.txt')

csv_a = csv.reader(class_a)

for row in csv_a:
    row[2] = int(row[2])
print(row[2])
```

When I run my program I get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Roo\Desktop\Python\Class\Test.py", line 7, in <module>
row[1]= int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code when run in python tells me there is a problem on line 13 with

```
"index out of range"
```

My text file contains:

```
Roo,2,3,3  
Roo,4,4,5  
Alfie,5,8,2    
Alfie,2,8,5    
Bob,2,8,6    
Connor,3,5,9    
Connor,5,3,3  
Ellis,5,6,2  
George,5,4,1   
Ellis,4,9,3   
Nathan,5,6,5   
George,5,5,6    
Alfie,9,4,7    
George,4,7,9    
Celis,4,5,4    
Leo,3,2,3    
Celis,6,1,2  
Leo,5,2,1
```

When I run the program the code, `row[2] = int(row[2])` tells me it's out of range? Any solutions?

Please keep it basic, im currently new at python and do not understand all of the technical terms

Comment: The 'Out of range' error is telling you the index of the item are looking for is outside of the range the array contains.  It's like asking a packet of biscuits for the 4th biscuit when there are only 2 left in the packet.

Comment: Note: using massive text files and storing all the scores for one class in a single text file is advised against. Using directories and then files is, in the long run, massively easier. I only know how to use this method, and it makes your development section of the controlled assessment much neater

Comment: Liwa,  would u be able to explain what you mean? I am interested in your method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably an empty line at
the end of `classA.txt`.

Use

```
for row in csv_a:
    if row:              # or better if len(row)==4:
          row[2] = int(row[2])
          print(row[2])
```

to check if the line is not empty, before
you access the second/third entry.

Comment: Thankyou I have sorted that error and now onto the next